# Retrieve from DB entity with LocalDate

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have a class with field `LocalDate` which I'd like to persist.

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
private Long id;    
private LocalDate issueDate;
// ... ///
// getters and setters
}
```

When I tried to get an object from database by executing

`Employee Employee = em.find(Employee.class, 1L)`

I get an exception:

```
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConversionException /..../
could not be converted to [class java.time.LocalDate
```

Then I followed that [tutorial](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1085303&goto=1758657&) and wrote converter between LocalDate and String. It works, but using `EclipseLink` and `MariaDB` I can only persist date in such a way: "yyyy-MM-dd". That way I cannot store hours, minutes and seconds. EclipseLink gives the following exception: `java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: HourOfDay`. How do I store more precise time?

My converter:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDate, String> {

    private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").toFormatter();

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDate locDate) {
        return (locDate == null ? null : locDate.format(formatter));
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute(String sqlDate) {
        return (sqlDate == null ? null : LocalDate.parse(sqlDate, formatter));
    }
}
```

Comment: "EclipseLink and MariaDB I can only persist date in such a way: "yyyy-MM-dd"" ??? I think not. Use propper columns type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i can see you have an error in your code,
since LocalDate have no parameters of time so you got that exception.

to fix your issue you should make those changes to your code in `DateTimeFormatter`

```
 private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").toFormatter();
```

make sure there are no time attr in the `DateTimeFormatter`

Comment: I would like to have more precise time than yyyy-MM-dd.

Comment: than you should change your  issueDate attr to LocalDateTime